# My Javascript doesn't seem to be working - could the DOM have changed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Like many of us, I want to keep my code as DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) as possible - and that includes my website.  I would like to do this by importing the common footer onto all pages - which is fine, and I'm doing this as follows:

page.html

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
      $("#footer").load("./Components/footer.html");
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body>
    This is my main page content
     
    <div id="footer"></div>  
  </body> 
</html>
```

footer.html

```
<div class="copyright-notice">
  <p align=center>
    Copyright © 2019 - <class id="getyear"></class> Joe Bloggs.
  </p>
</div>
<script>
  let d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("getyear").innerHTML = (new Date()).getFullYear();
</script>
```

The issue here the footer gets included - but it only contains the following:

`Copyright © 2019 -  Joe Bloggs.`

I expect it to contain:

`Copyright © 2019 - 2021 Joe Bloggs.`

I'm wondering if it's a DOM problem.  I can see, by the way, that the JavaScript is being executed - because if I put `<class id="getyear"></class>` into page.html then the JavaScript from footer.html works and puts the date in correctly.

It's a bit of a poser.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is no `class` element in HTML; [here's the list of elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3). As a result, `<class id="getyear"></class>` is invalid HTML (custom elements must have a `-` in them). I suspect the element is being relocated in the DOM in some way by the browser in an attempt to make it valid and the number is appearing, but not where you expect. Use a valid inline element, like a `span`.

Comment: Side note: You're never using the `d` variable in the script in `footer.html`.

Comment: _"...could the DOM have changed?"_ - That's quite easy to check in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: Try using `span` instead of `class`

Comment: The let d was a hangover from a previous stab.

Comment: the span fixed the issue.  How weird that class worked in the main html.  Never mind - the problem is fixed.  Thank you all.

Comment: T.J. Crowder - please put your first comment as an answer to this question, and harvest the points for the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working properly :)

This is the screenshot
[image]

page.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $("#footer").load("./footer.html");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is my main page content
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

footer.html

```
<div class="copyright-notice">
  <p align="center">
    Copyright © 2019 - <class id="getyear"></class> Joe Bloggs.
  </p>
</div>
<script>
  let d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("getyear").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
</script>
```